# How to force CouchDB to return attachments in base64 instead of MIME multipart/related?

Tags: ajax, couchdb, attachment

As described in http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/HTTP_Document_API#Getting_Attachments_With_a_Document , I can ask to return attachments together with the document attachments via `?attachments=true`.

**The Problem**

As the CouchDB wiki states, attachments can be returned either in plain JSON or MIME multipart/related.

> To get MIME multipart/related response format, just add an "Accept:" header to the
>   request with value "multipart/related".

For me, they are always returned in MIME multipart/related mode, even when no Accept: header is specified. Maybe web browser adds it, but I can't remove it either - and i need **plain JSON** (to process them with javascript)

**The Question**

What should I do to get attachments inline, -or- is this a CouchDB bug?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, the webbrowser sets

```
Accept: */*
```

So, the correct way is to reset the Accept header beforehand:

```
$.ajax({
beforeSend: function(req) {
    req.setRequestHeader("Accept", "");
    req.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json");
},
type: "GET",
url: "/db/doc/?attachments=true&rnd=_"+(new Date().getTime()),
contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
success: function(data) {
    $("#test").html(JSON.stringify(data));
},
error:function(xx,s,x){alert("e"+x.message+" "+x+" "+s);},
});
```